# Excel Send Mail to Value in Cell not working

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Trying to create vba that send specific sheets in the Excel as a new excel attached to mail. the only thing missing now is that the recipient should be dynamic, so as seen here it should be the value in B20. But it does not work. When i put in the email address directly (so "test@company.com") it works just fine so that already excludes some possible issues. I do not get error messages when executing and when i put another email in cc, it gets sent but the recipient is empty. so I'm wondering if maybe the issue is with the cell value itself but it is the exact same email address

```
Sub Mail_Sheets_Array()
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
    Dim TempWindow As Window

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    With Sourcewb
        Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
        Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
        .Sheets(Array("TEST PTOP", "TEST DES")).Copy
    End With

    TempWindow.Close

    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
              
        With OutMail
            .To = Range("B20").Value
            .cc = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .HTMLBody = "Hi all, <br> <br> Please find the <b>Excel</b> attached."
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Tried Range and Sheet function in vba, both do not work

Comment: You really should specify the workbook/worksheet for `Range("B20")`.

Comment: @BigBen tried that (.To = Sheets("MAIL").Range("B20").Value) and it didn't work either. am i missing something? Do i need to define the sheet even before that?

Comment: You're partway there. You didn't specify the workbook. Is it `Sourcewb`?

Comment: .To = Project.Sheets("MAIL").Range("B20").Value

still doesn't work :/

Comment: Where is `Project` defined or assigned a value in your code?

Comment: Nowhere since I assumed it would work being just the open workbook. Since this vba does work when i put in the email directly for to="". What do you recommend I do to fix this. I'm sorry I'm not very proficient in vba

Comment: If the code is in the same workbook as the email address then `.To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIL").Range("B20")`